# re-consume message after kafka broker restart

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

i use
./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --new-consumer --bootstrap-server 10.10.3.80:9092 --describe --group message-center-consumer-1
i found current offset is 337

and when we restart kafka broker , consumer will re consume message from 238 offset
why current offset was 337，and i receive 238 offset by kafka broker restart？
i use kafka auto commit is true(default) and auto commit interval ms is 5000 (default)

i use kafka broker is 0.11.0 and spring-kafka 1.1.6 and springboot 1.5.7

my github issue is https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/435

my question like
[(Solved) Kafka 0.11.0.0 keeps reseting offset on restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45810636/solved-kafka-0-11-0-0-keeps-reseting-offset-on-restart)

but i don't know how to solve

Comment: Any chance of simple application to let us play and reproduce locally?

Answer (score 0):

> I use kafka auto commit is true(default) and auto commit interval ms is 5000 (default)

That is the problem - the offsets are only committed every 5 seconds.

It's generally better to set it to false and let the container manage the commits (`AckMode.Record` for minimum reprocessing, but maximum overhead, `AckMode.BATCH` will commit after each batch of records received from the broker - less overhead but increased possibility of reprocessing).

Comment: thanks!  i am sure offset has been committed, weird is i use kafka-manager， current offset is 337， and lag is 0， but i restart kafka broker， my consumer app from 238 offset to re-consumer again， only my test env (centos 7 and one kafka broker) can reproduce， i use same code in my local macbook， have not is problem， tomorrow i will check the kafka's log in test env, and check  kafka-log,